# How to call an onClick Function when creating a span, In react

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am working in react and when a button is clicked, a li item gets created, in the list item I have a span with a glyphicon, i want to create an onClick event for the glyphicon, but it doesn't work.

Html

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

this is the method which creates the list item

```
var listItem = document.createElement("li");              
        listItem.innerHTML = this.tokenSeries;
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerHTML = "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' onClick={this.test}></span>" 
        listItem.appendChild(span);
        document.getElementById('list').appendChild(listItem);
```

this is my test method

```
@action.bound test() {
        alert("hello");
    }
```

Comment: You are using React at all in this code... you are using vanilla JavaScript with some (wrong) JSX!

Take a read to React tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I Hope its good :)

```
var listItem = document.createElement("li");              
    listItem.innerHTML = this.tokenSeries;
    var span = document.createElement("span").on('click', (e) => {
     //place to call function trigger
     this.test(e);
    });
    span.innerHTML = "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>" 
    listItem.appendChild(span);
    document.getElementById('list').appendChild(listItem);
```

Comment: I tried this but get an error of " Uncaught TypeError: document.createElement(...).on is not a function"

Comment: if you have setup webpack to include jquery,  you can used like: 
`jQuery('<span className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"/>').on('click', (e) => {this.test(e); return false});

Answer (score 1):

after setting the html set the onclick method to call the function you want

```
var listItem = document.createElement("li");              
            listItem.innerHTML = "text"
            var span = document.createElement("span");
            span.innerHTML = "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' ></span>" 
            span.onclick = this.test;
            listItem.appendChild(span);
            document.getElementById('list').appendChild(listItem);
```

Or you can create a function right there

```
 var listItem = document.createElement("li");              
                listItem.innerHTML = "text"
                var span = document.createElement("span");
                span.innerHTML = "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' ></span>" 
                span.onclick = function(){
                //write your function here
                };
                listItem.appendChild(span);
                document.getElementById('list').appendChild(listItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using React you can do it the React Way instead of going by the `VanillaJS` method

```
constructor() {
     super();
     this.state = {
          list: []
     }
}

addListItem = () => {
     var list = [...this.state.list];
     var ele= <li>{this.tokenSeries}<span className='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' onClick={this.test}></span></li>
     list.push(ele)
     this.setState({list})
}

//render

<ul id="list">{this.state.list}</ul>
```